# How to evaluate $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \left(\left(\frac{x+1}{x-1}\right)^x -e^2\right){x}^2$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, taylor-expansion, exponential-function

I want to find the limit of the following expression:
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \left(\left(\frac{x+1}{x-1}\right)^x -e^2\right){x}^2.$$

I got the limit of the first term as $e^2$ so the problem now becomes equivalent to evaluating a $0 \times \infty$  limit, but I'm having difficulty proceeding after this. I tried applying L'Hospital's rule but the derivative gets really complicated after a while. I also tried applying series expansions but that too got me nowhere.

Could anyone please tell me how to proceed with this problem?

Comment: ...Taylor expansion of $e^{\log((1+t)/(1-t))/t}$?

Comment: This question is a bit similar, maybe it can help : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1450708/limit-of-x-lefte-left-fracx2x1-rightx-right-when-x-to-infty

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint. Note that for $x>1$,
$$\begin{align}\left(\frac{x+1}{x-1}\right)^x&=
\exp\left(x\left(\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)-\ln\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)\right)\\&=\exp\left(2+\frac{2}{3x^2}+o(1/x^2))\right)=e^2\cdot \exp\left(\frac{2}{3x^2}+o(1/x^2))\right)\end{align}$$
where we used the expansion of $\ln(1+t)=t-\frac{t^2}{2}+\frac{t^3}{3}+o(t^3)$ at $t=0$. Hence
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \left(\left(\frac{x+1}{x-1}\right)^x -e^2\right){x}^2=e^2\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\exp\left(\frac{2}{3}(1/x^2)+o(1/x^2)\right)-1}{1/x^2}.$$
 Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes i definitely can take it from here. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Isham how can we evaluate directly without taylor?

Comment: @physics123 I thought you already had its value as $e^2$ ?

Comment: @Isham first term is $e^2$ and first factor tends to $0$. Thats what physics123 found.

Comment: @Isham Yes i had got that for the first term but couldn't proceed after that..That isn't the solution for the problem..

Comment: @Isham The result is not $e^2$...

Comment: @Isham no then you get $0$ straight away for that factor. what purpose will it serve?

Answer (score 6):

Let $t=\frac1x$.

We have that

$$\frac{2t}{1-t}=2t+2t^2+2t^3+O(t^4)$$

then

$$\left(\frac{1+t}{1-t}\right)^{1/t}=e^{\frac1t\log\left(1+\frac{2t}{1-t}\right)}=e^{\frac1t\left(2t+\frac23t^3+O(t^4)\right)}=e^2\left(1+\frac23t^2+O(t^3)\right)$$

and therefore

$$\frac{\left(\frac{1+t}{1-t}\right)^{1/t}-e^2}{t^2}=\frac{e^2\left(1+\frac23t^2+O(t^3)\right)-e^2}{t^2}$$

Comment: can you add some detail how are you getting $2/3 t^3$  in second line?

Comment: We need to use third order expansion for $\log(1+u)$ with $u=2t+2t^2+2t^3+o(t^4)$.

Comment: Try by yourself, I’ll add these details later if needed!

Comment: in the last line it should be e^(2{something}) and not e^2 * (something)

Comment: I think it’s fine that way, look at the previous steps.

Comment: @AnindyaPrithvi We have $$e^{\frac1t\left(2t+\frac23t^3+o(t^5)\right)}=e^{\left(2+\frac23t^2+o(t^4)\right)}=e^2e^{\left(\frac23t^2+o(t^4)\right)}=e^2\left(1+\frac23t^2+o(t^4)\right)$$

Comment: @user69608 Did you see the steps? These are $$\log (1+2t+2t^2+2t^3+o(t^4))=2t+2t^2+2t^3+o(t^4)-\frac12\left(2t+2t^2+2t^3+o(t^4)\right)^2+\frac13\left(2t+2t^2+2t^3+o(t^4)\right)^3+o(t^4)$$

Comment: I think you mean $e^2e^{\left(\frac23t^2+o(t^4)\right)}=e^2\left(1+\frac23t^3+o(t^5)\right)^{\frac{1}{t}}$.... or how does $e^{2/3t^2+o(t^4)}=(1+{2/3t^2+o(t^4)})$

Comment: @AnindyaPrithvi We have used $e^u=1+u+O(u^2)$. Now I realize that there is just an issue with the little-o, I fix that by Big-O notation but things don't change at all.

Answer (score 2):

Let $t=1/x$, then the limit becomes
$$\begin{aligned}L
&=\displaystyle{\lim_ {t\to 0^{+}}}\frac{\left(\frac{1+t}{1-t}\right)^{\frac{1}{t}}-e^2}{t^2} \\
&=\lim_{t\rightarrow0}\frac{e^{\frac{1}{t}\ln\frac{1+t}{1-t}}-e^2}{t^2}\\
&=\lim_{t\rightarrow0}\frac{\left(1+\frac{2t}{1-t}\right)^{\frac{1-t} {2t}\cdot\frac{2t}{(1-t)t}}\left(\frac{1}{t}\ln\frac{1+t}{1-t}\right)'}{2t} \\
&=e^2\lim_{t\rightarrow0}\frac{\left(\frac{1}{t}\ln\frac{1+t}{1-t}\right)'}{2t} \\
&=e^2\lim_{t\rightarrow0}\frac{-\ln\frac{1+t}{1-t}+\frac{2t}{1-t^2}}{2t^3} \\
&=e^2\lim_{t\rightarrow0}\frac{\left(-\ln\frac{1+t}{1-t}+\frac{2t}{1-t^2}\right)'}{6t^2} \\
&=e^2\lim_{t\rightarrow0}\frac{\frac{4t^2}{(1-t^2)^2}}{6t^2} \\
&=\boxed{\frac{2}{3}e^2} \end{aligned}$$

Comment: Step 2 to 3: is it 0/0?

Comment: Yes, of course. I added it.

Comment: $\frac{e^{\frac{0}{0}}-e^2}{0^2}=0/0?$

Comment: @C.F.G See please better my post. I showed it. See the following expression $\left(1+\frac{2t}{1-t}\right)^{\frac{1-t}{2t}\cdot\frac{2t}{(1-t)t}}$. It closed to $e^2$.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative we have

$$\frac{\left(\frac{1+t}{1-t}\right)^{1/t}-e^2}{t^2}=\frac{e^{\frac1t\log\left(\frac{1+t}{1-t}\right)}-e^2}{t^2}=e^2\cdot\frac{e^{\frac1t\log\left(\frac{1+t}{1-t}\right)-2}-1}{t^2}=$$

$$=e^2\cdot\frac{e^{\frac1t\log\left(\frac{1+t}{1-t}\right)-2}-1}{\frac1t\log\left(\frac{1+t}{1-t}\right)-2}\cdot\frac{\frac1t\log\left(\frac{1+t}{1-t}\right)-2}{t^2}$$

with the standard limit

$$\frac{e^{\frac1t\log\left(\frac{1+t}{1-t}\right)-2}-1}{\frac1t\log\left(\frac{1+t}{1-t}\right)-2} \to 1$$

and by $\log(1+u)=u-\frac12u^2+\frac13u^3+o(u^3)$

$$\frac{\frac1t\log\left(\frac{1+t}{1-t}\right)-2}{t^2}=\frac{\log(1+t)-\log(1-t)-2t}{t^3} \to\frac23$$